# pcl visualizer What's the meaning of getViewerPose

Tags: point-cloud-library

I don't quite understand what pose is returned by pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::getViewerPose. Is this pose relative to the viewer? or something else? If yes, how is the initial pose of the viewer defined?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the code](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/visualization/src/pcl_visualizer.cpp#L2020-L2053), the `getViewerPose` is just retrieving camera pose.

```cpp
pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::getViewerPose (int viewport)
{
  Eigen::Affine3f ret (Eigen::Affine3f::Identity ());

  rens_->InitTraversal ();
  vtkRenderer* renderer = nullptr;
  if (viewport == 0)
    viewport = 1;
  int viewport_i = 1;
  while ((renderer = rens_->GetNextItem ()))
  {
    if (viewport_i == viewport)
    {
      vtkCamera& camera = *renderer->GetActiveCamera ();
      Eigen::Vector3d pos, x_axis, y_axis, z_axis;
      camera.GetPosition (pos[0], pos[1], pos[2]);
      camera.GetViewUp (y_axis[0], y_axis[1], y_axis[2]);
      camera.GetFocalPoint (z_axis[0], z_axis[1], z_axis[2]);

      z_axis = (z_axis - pos).normalized ();
      x_axis = y_axis.cross (z_axis).normalized ();

      ret.translation () = pos.cast<float> ();
      ret.linear ().col (0) << x_axis.cast<float> ();
      ret.linear ().col (1) << y_axis.cast<float> ();
      ret.linear ().col (2) << z_axis.cast<float> ();

      return ret;
    }
    viewport_i ++;
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanksf for your answer!